# Failed to convert NeDB Node callback to Bacon EventStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, bacon.js, nedb

Below the `Node callback` on `NeDB` worked correctly,

```
Datastore = require 'nedb'
db = new Datastore

db.insert a: 'Hi!', (err, docs) -> 
    console.log docs
```

Then tried to convert `NeDB Node callback` to `Bacon EventStream`,

```
Bacon = require('baconjs').Bacon
Datastore = require 'nedb'
db = new Datastore

insert = Bacon.fromNodeCallback db.insert, a: 'Hi!'

insert.onValue (docs) ->
    console.log docs
```

Why did it fail below?

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to post the question either in the NeDB or Bacon issue page on GitHub if you don't receive any answers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `db.insert` that way, you lose its evaluation context ("this" is no longer the database). Try using the other form of `fromNodeCallback`:

```
insert = Bacon.fromNodeCallback(db, 'insert', {a: 'Hi!'})
```